# going to the next page of a list with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```html
<table class="pagerRegion">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftRegion">Seite&nbsp;<span class="currentPage">1</span>&nbsp;von 2 Seiten</td>
            <td class="centerRegion">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="pager firstPage"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="pager previousPage"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="goosProductGridViewModel.GotoPage(1)" class="pager page active">1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="goosProductGridViewModel.GotoPage(2)" class="pager page">2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a onclick="goosProductGridViewModel.GotoPage(2)" class="pager nextPage"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a onclick="goosProductGridViewModel.GotoPage(2)" class="pager lastPage"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="rightRegion"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Dear Community, 
i am trying to get to the next page of a list but i couldn't so far access it with the xpath css or name
This `nextpage=driver.find_element_by_xpath("table[@id='ProductGrid']/tfoot/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span[3]")
nextpage.click()`
Always ends up in a no such element exception.

I already used the google chrome tool to inspect the html 
does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

why not use a more simple selector for the span you want to click on :
I recommend you read more about [css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [xpath selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

```
nextpage = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="pager page"]')
if nextpage :
    nextpage[0].click()
```